# Error in cloudbees build: unable to find pom.xml

Tags: build, pom.xml, cloudbees

When I build my cloudbees project it gives the following error:

```
ERROR: No such file /scratch/jenkins/workspace/glassfish-myruby/pom.xml
```

Where my project name is `glassfish-myruby`.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the job you created and click on the "Workspace" link on the left. This will show you how your project was checked out. The pom may be in a different place than you expect.

Comment: When I click on the Workspace I am not able to locate any pom.xml file in the workspace area.

Comment: Is anything in the workspace? Check the console output and make sure it was able to clone/checkout your repository.

Comment: This the output:Started by user Jayasurya Venugopalan
Building remotely on s-4b7a9f10 in workspace /scratch/jenkins/workspace/glassfish-myruby
Updating https://svn-jayavenu.forge.cloudbees.com/mymaven
At revision 0
no change for https://svn-jayavenu.forge.cloudbees.com/mymaven since the previous build
Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file /scratch/jenkins/workspace/glassfish-myruby/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
Sending e-mails 
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You are checking an empty Subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. My project was building fine, then suddenly stopped with the same error:

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file /scratch/jenkins/workspace/MyMoney/pom.xml
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
[cloudbees-deployer] Skipping deployment as build result is FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I realized the only thing I had changed was adding a GitHub page (as described in http://pages.github.com/)
For reasons I don't understand, this was causing my project to check out from the gh-pages branch instead of master, as reflected in the console output:

```
Commencing build of Revision 88d8d7ee822e02aa2cdae11e07265eb7a8403fed (origin/gh-pages)
```

This was also reflected in the jenkins workspace (it contained the GitHub pages files, rather than my project files).

I'm sure there is a way to get this to work AND use GitHub pages, but for me the GitHub page was just an experiment, so I deleted the branch using:

```
git push origin --delete gh-pages
```

I then also did another commit to make sure all was OK and rebuilt.
The project is now checking out from master again and building OK.